# Adding children to pane after stage.show()

Tags: java, javafx

I'm writing a simple game application in JavaFX and am trying to implement a restart game function. My initial thought was to take the gameView pane, remove its children, and then re-add clean ones. For some reason, this doesn't work. Is there another method for adding/removing children to a pane in scene after the stage is already shown?

Start method:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    guessedLetters = new ArrayList<>();
    wrongGuesses = new ArrayList<>();

    gameView = getPane();

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hangman");
    Scene scene = new Scene(gameView);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    //primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    primaryStage.show();
    primaryStage.setMinHeight(scene.getHeight());
    primaryStage.setMinWidth(scene.getWidth());
    primaryStage.sizeToScene();
}
```

Reset logic:

```
 private void reset() {
            numMistakes = 0;
            guessedLetters.clear();
            wrongGuesses.clear();
            gameView.getChildren().clear();
            gameView = getPane();
            // ToDo: figure out how to reset pane
        }
```

getPane() initializes and returns new gameView pane:

```
private BorderPane getPane() {
    // Text-input section
    lblInput = new Label("Guess a letter: ");
    tfInput = new TextField();

    tfInput.setOnAction(e -> play());
    guessInput = new HBox();
    guessInput.getChildren().addAll(lblInput, tfInput);
    guessInput.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);


    gallows = new Gallows();
    gameBoard = buildGameBoard();
    centerScreen = new VBox();
    centerScreen.getChildren().addAll(gallows, gameBoard, guessInput);
    centerScreen.setSpacing(10);
    centerScreen.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    centerScreen.setPadding(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
    lblOutput = new Label();
    lblOutput.setFont(Font.font("Georgia", 15));

    gameView = new BorderPane();
    gameView.setCenter(centerScreen);
    gameView.setBottom(lblOutput);
    BorderPane.setAlignment(lblOutput, Pos.CENTER);

    return gameView;
}
```

If not, what other methods of resetting a scene in a window (without opening a new window) are available?

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You replace the field value of `gamePane`, but you never display the new `BorderPane` in the window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Stage stage = (Stage) gameView.getScene().getWindow();
gameView = getPane();
stage.setScene(gameView);
```

Side question: Why does `getPane` return `gameView` even though it seems that `gameView` is a member variable rather than a local variable of that method?